# Is Disposables no longer in RxJava 3.0.0?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

In RxJava 2.x.x, I can initialize my disposable as below.

```
var disposable = Disposables.disposed()
```

However in RxJava 3.0.0, the `Disposables` is non existence already. Is it removed, or did I miss something?

Comment: You missed reading the release log. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-3.0#disposables

Answer (score 0):

See commit https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/commit/166c529eb165b473c9bff11e8fedbde6c471b005

See PR https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6781

> **Migrate Disposables static factories to Disposable interface**

Therefore, in RxJava3, the method is moved to `Disposable.disposed()`.